# gameObject.GetComponent returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a problem.

In one of my scripts when I try to get a component it return me null with this error in console: "NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required."

I don't know why because in other files the process I use works fine.

Here my code flow: First one - GameController.cs

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    private SpawningPositions spawningPositions; //IT WORKS

    private void Awake()
    {
        spawningPositions = GetComponent<SpawningPositions>(); //IT WORKS
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (enemyWaveTypes.Length != 0 && wavesNumberEnemy.Length != 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnShips());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnShips()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < wavesNumberEnemy[waveCounter]; i++)
            {
                spawningPositions.SpawnRandom(enemyShip); //IT WORKS // NEXT SCRIPT
            }
            waveCounter++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveTimingRatio);
        }
    }
}
```

Second One - SpawningPositions.cs

```
public class SpawningPositions : MonoBehaviour {

    GeoData geoData; //IT WORKS

    private void Awake()
    {
        geoData = GetComponent<GeoData>(); //IT WORKS
    }

    public void SpawnRandom(Transform enemyShip)
    {
        Vector3 spawnPosition;
        Tuple<int, float> tuple = geoData.GetRandomOuterBoundary();  //IT WORKS (i've got a custom class for Tuples)
        int randomSpawn = tuple.Item1;
        float randomPosition = tuple.Item2;
        spawnPosition = geoData.GetRandomPointIn(tuple);
        Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        var myEnemy = Instantiate(enemyShip, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
        myEnemy.gameObject.AddComponent<FixedPointAndGo>(); // NEXT SCRIPT
    }

}
```

And the last one, where I've got the problem - FixedPointAndGo.cs

```
public class FixedPointAndGo : MonoBehaviour {

    GeoData geoData; // DOESN'T WORK!!!

    private void Awake()
    {
        geoData = gameObject.GetComponent<GeoData>();  // DOESN'T WORK!!! return NULL
    }

    private void Start()
    {       
        endPos = new Vector3(
            Random.Range(
                (geoData.horizontalInLimits.x - 2), // DOESN'T WORK!!!
                (geoData.horizontalInLimits.y - 2) // DOESN'T WORK!!!
            ),
            0,
            Random.Range(geoData.verticalInLimits.x, geoData.verticalInLimits.y) // DOESN'T WORK!!!
        );
    }
}
```

Why when I try to add the component `GeoData` in the second script works and not in the third? I cannot understand.

I tried to search solutions in this forum and in the documentation but I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
geoData = gameObject.GetComponent<GeoData>();  // DOESN'T WORK!!! return NULL
```

Notice the variable "`gameObject`". This refers to this GameObject this script (`FixedPointAndGo`) is attached to.

This means that `gameObject.GetComponent<GeoData>()` will return `null` **only** if the `GeoData` script is **not** attached to the GameObject your `FixedPointAndGo` script is attached to.

Attach `GeoData` to the-same GameObject your `FixedPointAndGo`  script is attached to.

---

If  `GeoData` is attached to another GameObject and you want to access it then find that GameObject first before accessing the  `GeoData` componet attached to it.

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectGeoDataIsAttachedTo"); 
geoData = obj.GetComponent<GeoData>();
```

---

Finally if `GeoData` script is already attached to the-same GameObject `FixedPointAndGo` script is attached to but you are still getting `null` then you have mistakenly attached another `FixedPointAndGo` script to an empty GameObject or another GameObject which does not have the `GeoData` script attached to it.

Find that GameObject and remove the `FixedPointAndGo` script from it. You can do this by selecting your `FixedPointAndGo` script and then go to *Assets* ---> *Find References In Scene* and remove the script.